# Declaring too many variables will reduce the performance of the program?

Tags: swift, compiler-optimization

I declare a lot of variables because I want to improve readability. I read in some blogs that:

> declaring too many variables will reduce the  performance of the program.

I have 2 questions that I would like someone to answer for me:

1. Is that correct? If it is correct, how can I realize that I have declared too many variables?
2. Will the Swift compiler be able to optimize this so I can be more comfortable with variable declarations?

Comment: Who said that? They quite likely have very little idea what they're talking about, unless they're referring to some totally different language. This might be true in a non-optimized, interpreted language where local variables are basically just values keyed by strings a dictionary. But even still, you're unlikely to be able to write so many variables by hand that it would be an issue. Readability would be more important, in any case.

Comment: @Alexander the quote is wrong in swift context?

Comment: It's wrong in practically every non-toy compiled language. Variable in-lining is like the most simple optimization pass ever, there's no compiler worth its salt that doesn't implement it. Variables are just meaningless words we put into source for our own clarity. They're one of the first things to get stripped out when the compiler starts lowering your code.